# How we use ggplot2like if there is already a user defined par.settings function

Tags: r, plot, lattice

The example from the ggplot2like help returns ggplot2like() to par.settings,
as follows:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

xyplot(exp(1:10) ~ 1:10, type = "b", 
  par.settings = ggplot2like(), axis = axis.grid)
```

But how shall we use **ggplot2like** and **axis = axis.grid** if we have already a user-defined
function for par.settings, as follows:

```
mysettings <- list(par.main.text = list(font = 1, cex = 1))

xyplot(exp(1:10) ~ 1:10, type = "b", main = "Title",
  par.settings = mysettings)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `modifyList` can be used to modify `ggplot2like` theme:

```
mysettings <- list(par.main.text = list(font = 1, cex = 1))

xyplot(exp(1:10) ~ 1:10, type = "b", main = "Title",
  par.settings = modifyList(ggplot2like(), mysettings), axis = axis.grid)
```

Works because a lattice theme is list of parameters. Function `modifyList` use second list to modify (add or replace) elements in first list.

[image: modified plot]

As an alternative you could setup your settings  at first:

```
mysettings <- modifyList(
    ggplot2like()
    ,list(par.main.text = list(font = 1, cex = 1))
)

xyplot(exp(1:10) ~ 1:10, type = "b", main = "Title",
  par.settings = mysettings, axis = axis.grid)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Marek. Very clear and intuitive answer.